# Cron Job - How to send an output file to an email

Tags: cron

I have this line in crontab:

```
* * * * * /var/www/dir/sh/mysql_dumb.sh | mail -s "mysql_dump" example@mail.com
```

(every minute only a sample)

So, all works fine, but the email is empty.

**UPDATE:**

The output from mysql_dumb.sh is a `*.sql` file and they save the file in a directory.

How can I send a copy (*.sql file) from this output -> `mysql_dumb.sh` to my email?

mysql_dumb.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DATABASE > /var/www/dir/backup/backup_DB_`date +%d_%m_%Y`.sql
```

Comment: as a tip, you can prevent empty email from being sent, by using the `-E` flag (`mail -E -s ...`)

Comment: @shx2 that's not what the --help says,  -E, --exec=COMMAND         execute COMMAND

Comment: @shx2 nevermind, I needed to sudo apt-get install bsd-mailx . http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/bsd-mailx.1.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If the script is reporting errors, they may be going to `stderr`, but you're only redirecting `stdout`. You can redirect `stderr` by adding `2>&1` to the command:

```
* * * * * /var/www/dir/sh/mysql_dump.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "mysql_dump" example@mail.example
```

Comment: Hi.. I update my question. It`s the same result for me... An empty email.

Comment: Why don't you put `cat XXX.sql` in the script, so that the contents of the file will be included in the email?

Comment: Just to expand a bit, you look at mysql_dumb.sh you'll notice:
```/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DATABASE > /var/www/[...]```

The `>` is redirecting the output of mysqldump from stdout to that file.

Comment: @W3tTr3y That's why he should add `cat /var/www/...` to the script.

Answer (score 42):

From a crond perspective more accurate is to place in to your cron:

```
MAILTO=example@mail.com
* * * * * /var/www/dir/sh/mysql_dumb.sh
* * * * * /var/www/dir/sh/other.sh
* * * * * /var/www/dir/sh/other2.sh
```

Comment: This will send emails for all entries in the crontab, not just the one line.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the last line of mysql_dumb.sh:
`` /usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DATABASE > /var/www/dir/backup/backup_DB_`date +%d_%m_%Y`.sql ``

The `>` is redirecting the output of `mysqldump` to the file `/var/www/dir/backup/backup_DB_`date +%d_%m_%Y`.sql`

Do you want to store a backup of the database locally?

If not, take out the the `` > /var/www/dir/backup/backup_DB_`date +%d_%m_%Y`.sql `` and put the crontab entry back to

`* * * * * /var/www/dir/sh/mysql_dump.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "mysql_dump" example@mail.example`

If you do want a copy of the file locally, I would suggest using `tee` which will write the output to the file and put the output back out on stdout, which will later be picked up by crontab.

I would change the last line of `mysql_dumb.sh` to be:
`` /usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DATABASE | tee /var/www/dir/backup/backup_DB_`date +%d_%m_%Y`.sql ``

Again I would change the crontab entry back to:
`` /usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DATABASE > /var/www/dir/backup/backup_DB_`date +%d_%m_%Y`.sql ``

The advantage here is mail can read the information from stdout and isn't dependent on the file being written and then read correctly.  While that may be a small difference, in my experience using tee will be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **store** your cron job's output on the **file on server** and also want to send that **output file** to your **mail address** then you can use below command.

And you can use it on cronjob to automatically run on specific **interval of time**, here i am dumping mysql db and sending it to my mail with attachment of dumped `sql` file.

```
* * * * * mysqldump --user username --password='p@ssword' DBNAME | gzip > /home/user/db_backup/db_backup_`date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%H-\%M`.sql.gz && mailx -a /home/user/db_backup/db_backup_`date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%H-\%M`.sql.gz -s 'database backup date:'`date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%H:\%M` example@gmail.com
```