# Making PHP Script Automatically write to text file

Tags: php

I am writing a script to try and help make my day to day work easier. It works in parts, sending requests to an API and receiving responses. I then want it to save said responses in a text file that will be automatically emailed to a defined mailbox. The bit I am stuck with, is actually making my script save to a text file.

This is my script: (I'm not very experienced.. the include files aren't relevant, as they send requests the the API and contain nothing else.) I'm hoping that i can literally add a line at the bottom after the SQL connection closes to tell it to save to the text file. Also, I would like the text file to take the name of the "$CorrectCLI" variable.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

```
// Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Could Not Connect, Contact Support.";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Connected to Database Successfully.<br><br>";
    }

//Required Information:
    $CorrectCLI = $CLIrow[0];
    $CorrectSitename = $SiteNamRow[0];
    $CorrectSiteNumber = $SiteNumRow[0];
    $CorrectIP = $IProw[0];;


$xrefFromKF = "503269";
echo nl2br("Affected XREF: " . $xrefFromKF . "\n");
$CLIquery = "select primary_cli from customers where xref = " . $xrefFromKF . "";
$CLIresult = mysqli_query($con,$CLIquery);

if(!$CLIresult) {
    echo "Could Not Locate CLI In Database.<br>";
}

$CLIrow = mysqli_fetch_row($CLIresult);
$CLI = $CLIrow[0];
echo nl2br("Circuit CLI: 0" . $CLIrow[0] . "<br>");

if(!$CLI > 0 ) {
    echo " Could Not Locate CLI.<br>";
    }

$IPquery =  "select manufacturers_ip_prim from customers where primary_cli = " . $CLIrow[0] . "";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$IPquery);

if(!$result) {
    echo "Could Not Locate Management IP.<br>";
}

$IProw = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$IPcount = $IProw[0];
echo nl2br("Circuit IP: " . $IProw[0] . "");

if(!$IPcount > 0 ) {
    echo " Could Not Locate Management IP.<br>";
    }

        echo nl2br("\n\nPinged " . $IPcount . "...\n");
        exec("ping -c 2 " . $IPcount, $output1, $result1);

        if ($result1 == 0) {
            echo nl2br("Circuit Recovered - Cancelled Diagnostics.");
        } else {
            echo nl2br("Circuit Down - Starting Diagnostics");
            // Perform Sync Check
            include '../diags/SyncStatus.php';
            // Perform Data Port Reset
            include '../diags/DataPortReset.php';
                // sleep(10);

            echo nl2br("\nPinged " . $IPcount . "...\n");

            exec("ping -c 2 " . $IPcount, $output2, $result2);

            if ($result2 == 0) {
                echo nl2br("Circuit Recovered - Stopping Diagnostics.");
                } else {
                echo nl2br("Circuit Still Down - Continuing Diagnostics\n\n");
                include '../diags/Metascript.php';  
                include '../diags/TAMtestSubmit.php';
                include '../diags/TAMtestRetrieve.php'; 
                    echo "<br>";            
                include '../diags/GetProfile.php';
                    echo "<br>";
                include '../diags/ProfileOverride.php';
                    echo "<br>";
                // sleep(300);
                include '../diags/RevertProfile.php';
                    echo "<br>";

                echo nl2br("\nPinged " . $IPcount . "...\n");

                exec("ping -c 2 " . $IPcount, $output4, $result4);
                    //print_r($output4);

                if ($result4 == 0) {
                    echo nl2br("Circuit Recovered - Stopping End Of Diagnostics.");
                } else {
                    echo nl2br("Circuit Still Down - Requires Attention.\n\n");
                }

            }
        }

// Close the Database Connection
    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: This is the output from the script, and what i would like saving. Connected to Database Successfully.

Affected XREF: 503269
Circuit CLI: 01484428692
Circuit IP: 172.31.122.215

Pinged 172.31.122.215...
Circuit Down - Starting Diagnostics

Sync Check Result: Circuit In Sync.
Data Port Reset: 

Pinged 172.31.122.215...
Circuit Still Down - Continuing Diagnostics

Metascript Test: 
TAM Test: Submitted
TAM Test Result: 

Current Profile: SI16_2M_1M
Profile Changed to FIDiag.
Reverted Profile to SI16_2M_1M.

Pinged 172.31.122.215...
Circuit Still Down - Requires Attention.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: If you are running this as a `CRON JOB` you could have it email the output (example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887133/cron-job-send-copy-from-output-to-an-email)

Comment: none of your code does anything but echo, so use output buffering to capture the output: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: @cmorrissey: Or, a lot easier if you're using a cron script that `echo`es its output: `php /path/to/script.php 2&1 >> /path/to/log.txt` (append `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file). Oh, and to the OP: what's with the `echo nl2br('A string constant');`? the string constants don't contain any line terminators, so why bother calling `nl2br`? Besides, if you're goign to write the output to a log, you don't want it to contain _markup_ (at least, I wouldn't want that)

Comment: Sidenote: `$conn->close();` you're using `$con` as your connection variable everywhere else.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well Spotted. Thanks. To everyone else, I'll give it a go and come back if i have any more issues. As to "nl2br", they were added at an earlier stage, then the code changed and I haven't removed them yet. That's all. I'm still testing this bit by bit as I progress to ensure i don't break anything else.

Comment: You're welcome Scott. I may not always solve posted code, but when I recognize differences, I signal them when I do see them. *Cheers!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the PHP output buffer.

Add this code to the top of this PHP script

```
ob_start("process_output");
function process_output($buffer){
        $pageContent = $buffer;
        // $pageContent is all the output of your web page, 
        // put your email logic here
        return $pageContent;
}
```

In your logic I would reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php